# How can I return an array of all items in the provided array that include a singular item

Tags: arrays, typescript, arraylist, methods, filtering

I'm following theses instructions: "Return an array of all the people in the provided array who know typescript"

```js
export interface Person {
    name: string,
    netWorth: number,
    coder?: boolean,
    us?: boolean
    city: string,
    languages: string[]
}

export const cities = ['nyc', 'sf', 'la']
export const languages = [
    'javascript',
    'typescript',
    'html',
    'css',
    'c#',
    'python',
    'ruby',
]
```

I thought it would be as simple as:

```js
export function allCodersWhoKnowTypescript(people: Person[]): Person[] {
    people = people.filter(languages => languages === ('typescript'))

    return people
    }
```

But am getting the error:

```
This condition will always return `false` since the types `Person` and `string` have no overlap.
```

Comment: Please mention what programming language you are using. Putting that programming language in a tag and in the title would help to draw attention to your concern.

Answer (score 2):

From your code I assumed that the language being used is TypeScript or JavaScript.

Your anonymous function on people is incorrect.  The anonymous function is called with an instance of person which then contains language.  That's why you received the error you did.  `languages` in your statement is of type `Person` and that will never be equal to a string.

You can also put the entire filter on the return statement as follows:

```
export function allCodersWhoKnowTypescript(people: Person[]): Person[] {
    return people.filter(p => p.languages.indexOf('typescript')>=0)
    }
```

The code above doesn't generate any errors.  This did pass limited testing.